# Issue with MoviePy: Writing corrupted video files with h264 codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, h.264, moviepy

I'm encountering an issue with MoviePy where it's producing corrupted video files using the h264 codec. In my code, I have specified that I want to use the latest version of FFmpeg:

```py
change_settings({"FFMPEG_BINARY": r"C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"})
```

The FFmpeg version I'm using is 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev, built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project).

Here's my MoviePy version:

```
pip show moviepy
Name: moviepy
Version: 1.0.3
```

I'm editing a relatively simple video with some "crossfadeout," "crossfadein," a bit of "CompositeVideoClip," and a bit more of "concatenate_videoclips."

First, I obtain three short video clips, combine them, and end up with two desired clips. Here's the final part of my script:

```
t = VideoFileClip(a.title.video)
s = VideoFileClip(a.story.video)
e = VideoFileClip(a.end.video)
short = concatenate_videoclips([s, e])
short.write_videofile(shorts_folder, **preset_video)
sh = VideoFileClip(shorts_folder)
full = concatenate_videoclips([t, sh])
full.write_videofile(full_path, **preset_video)
```

And here are the settings for video recording:

```py
preset_video = {
    "fps": 30,
    "preset": "fast",
    "codec": "h264_nvenc",
    "threads": 4,
    "bitrate": '9000k',
    "audio_codec": 'aac',
    "audio_bitrate": '64k',
    "audio_fps": 22050,
    "verbose": True,
    "logger": 'bar'
}
```

(I specifically want to use the h264 codec, and I've tried other types with the same result.)

Here's the information about the resulting file:

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 720x1280 30fps 8718kbps [V: h264 high 4:4:4 predictive L3.2, gbrp, 720x1280, 8718 kb/s]
Audio: AAC 22050Hz stereo 64kbps [A: SoundHandler (aac lc, 22050 Hz, stereo, 64 kb/s)]
```

The first issue I noticed when playing the video on my desktop is that I can't rewind it smoothly. I can only jump to specific points, and there are approximately five such points throughout the timeline. I've tried multiple players.

Secondly, when I share the video on Telegram, it can't play the video, and I see the message "App was unable to play this video..." (I'll attach a screenshot.)

Clearly, there's something wrong with the file. How can I write a properly functioning video clip?

Comment: Corrupted video file - you may want to consider sharing your corrupted video.